# An issue with perl datatype conversion

Tags: perl-data-structures

My question is: I have something like this in my code

```
my $offset  = ‘0x4’
```

Out of this I want to extract only the value 4 and store it in a variable and discard ‘0x’, how can I do it.

Please note that this is just an example the values will keep changing so I want an generic way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to always discard "0x" in the beginning?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in many ways in Perl
1. You can use regex 
2. You can use subsrting 
3. You can even split on basis of x.
If it is a Hex value u can use Bit::Vector to convert to Decimal Value